# Does android support Cookies?

Tags: android, node.js, express, okhttp, express-session

I familiar with storing [JWT](https://jwt.io/) in android SharedPreferences and passing them via headers and then extract them on server using [express-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session). I used this way for some of previous projects and it worked well.

The biggest drawback I think when using JWT is that are very hard to revoke. Now I need server to have full control to all users session and I was wondering if android will support this?

I am using Redis as session store and currently I just have react web client where session id is stored in cookie and used every time React client makes a request! Can use similar manner to android app, session id as cookie/ or in sharedPreferences and send it along every requests?

Is this good idea? Or Is there better way? All I need is fully control of user sessions.

Note: My server is using GraphQL.

Comment: Checkout CookieJar interface https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CookieJar.html and google for examples / implementations.